# How to perfectly scale the whole webpage so that it is compatible with all the browsers?

Tags: html, css

I have a website which needs to be zoomed permanently with approx. 125%.

I tried:

```
body{
  zoom: 125%;
}
```

Also tried:

```
body{
  zoom: 125%;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.25);
  -moz-transform-origin: left top;
}
```

to be compatible with Mozilla Firefox.

It zooms. It was OK! But the webpage is shifted towards right i.e. its not zooming perfectly. Please help how can i fix this?

Comment: What do you want to zoom? a main div? background on the body,...

Answer (score 0):

for body use

```
body{
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
-webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
-moz-transform: scale(1.25);
transform: scale(1.25);
zoom: 125%;
}
```

and for making center all content use any container like this (use max-width according to your need)

```
.container {
max-width: 1160px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```